# Разбить данные для отправки по UDP

Tags: c#, сокет, udp

Есть данные 8 Кб, нужно по протоколу UDP отправить их клиенту по 32 байта.
Как правильно разбить данные? и как правильно их принять?

Comment: 8 байт на 32 байта сложно поделить и получить при этом целое число ... А 0.25 байта ну ни как не передается, хотя можно посылать 1 байт в котором заполнены только 2 бита. И главное, зачем их разбивать, максимальный размер пакета гораздо больше, а мелкие пакеты создают не нужную нагрузку на сеть

Comment: Это я косякнул в когда писал, 8 кб нужно передать

Comment: А почему UDP, а не TCP? По UDP можно запросто некоторые куски не получить, или получить не в том порядке, а TCP вам и порядок обеспечит, и повторную передачу потеряшек.

Comment: разбиваете по 32 байта, по моему это невозможно сделать как то "не правильно", в передаваемых пакетах предусматриваете дополнительное поле содержащие например смещение текущего блока от начала данных. на принимающей стороне проверяете его и кладете байты точно в указанное место буфера (это на случай, если пакеты придут не в том порядке) так же надо предусмотреть что бы сервер мог перезапросить у передающего какие то блоки, если они не были получены за отведенное время (на случай потери пакетов), например направляя клиенту список ожидаемых блоков

Comment: Все зависит от задачи, одно если нужно доставить в целости и сохранности, другое - потеряется несколько кадров и ладно. В общем: разбиваете 8к на размер кадра (например 1024 байта) + возможно служебная информация, устанавливаете соединение и последовательно отправляете, на принимающей стороне выполняете сборку( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864999/sending-and-receiving-udp-packets)